# JQuery - improving my function

Tags: jquery

I have a client who uses a WYSIWYG editor to create new website pages. The problem is that sometime the WYSIWYG editor put in empty p tags

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

This was causing havoc with the layout so i wrote a little function to remove these empty tags

```
$('p')
.filter(function() {
   return $.trim($(this).text()) === ''
})
.remove()
```

The problem now is that when a image is inserted into the wysiwyg editor it get's included in a p tag and my function removes it from the screen.

Can either my function be updated to allow images or can I just search for and remove empty p tags???

Thanks in advance

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your filter also ensure that there are no child elements:

```
$('p').filter(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    return !$this.children().length && $.trim($this.text()) === '';
}).remove()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) pseudo-selector to only select elements that have no children:

```
$("p:empty").remove();
```

However, if you have `p` elements with white-space and nothing else they will not be removed (because `:empty` treats text nodes as children). So you may want to remove white space (using `.trim`) from your `p` elements before running the above.

The problem with your current method is that tags like `img` do not contain any text, so your `filter` function thinks a `p` element containing only an `img` element should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('p').not(':has("img")')
.filter(function() {
   return $.trim($(this).text()) === ''
})
.remove()
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6sLTm/).

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
$('p').each(function(){
    if($(this).html() == "&nbsp;"){
        $(this).remove();  
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/krVBd/

Answer (score 1):

Just fix WYSIWYG, if it is javascript, if not, then fix at backend not frontend.

Comment: This is most probably the best course of action actually. It's a bug; kill it at the source instead of working around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using div tags around the blocks you want removed such as . In your jQuery statement you can then call based off the div id instead of all paragraphs.